# Javascript: Passing arguments from multiple functions to 1 function

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I have several functions that evaluate some variables and come up with a result

For example:

```
function first(){
   //variable declarations
   var result1 = a+b
}

function two(){
   //variable declarations
   var result2 =c+d 
}
```

I want to pass both of those results to another function

```
function three( result1, result2 ) {
   var finalResult = result1 + result2;
}
```

My question is where do I call function 3 from. because in reality I have about 10 functions with results I need to pass. Do I put three(result#) at the end of each???

thankyou

Comment: Where are `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` coming from? Are they global variables?

Comment: Hi, they are local. The come from fields in an html form

Comment: just to elaborate each function takes a value from the form field and then uses switch case to assign a score. It is the scores that I then want to pass to the main function to add up.

Comment: Where do I call 3 from. How can we answer that? Call it from wherever you like.

Comment: Just return something and use the function, I don't see the point of your question really...

Comment: I am a beginner so thanks heaps to those who have provided answers. I will work through them. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach you could take, although the question is a little vague.

```
function first(){
 return a+b;
} 

function two(){
 return c+d;
}

function three(){
 var finalResult = first() + two();
}
```

Or, if you didn't want the value in a function, you could do this:

```
<script>
 var results = first() + two();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function first() {
    return a + b;
}

function two() {
    return c + d;
}

function three(result1, result2) {
    return result1 + result2;
}
```

Call it:

```
var finalResult = three(first(), two());
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way is to pass an **object**. It will make sure if you want to put more details, you wont have to add more arguments in the function and make it more **readable**.

```
function first(){
    return "value of one";
} 

function second(){
    return "value of two";
}


function three(data){
    var finalResult = data.first + data.second;
}
```

ANd call it like:

```
var data = {};
data.first = first();
data.second = second();

three(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with the global results, i.e. `result1`,`result2` etc. Just return the data and call 3 when ready with all

```
function first(){
 return a+b;
} 

function two(){
  return c+d;
}

function three(){
     return (first() + two());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function one( a, b ) {
   var result1 = a + b;
   return result1;
}

function two( c, d ) {
   var result2 = c + d;
   return result2;
}

function three( a, b ) {
   var finalResult = a + b;
   return finalResult;
}
```

To call it use `three( one(), two() );`